# How to iterate through two lists at the same time?

Tags: c++

I have two `std::list<std::string> list1` `std::list<std::string> list2` and I need to somehow loop through them at the same time.

I tried a couple things like using `std::transform` and doing `std::transform (list1.begin(), list1.end(), list2.begin(), list2.end());` but sadly had no luck.

What I'm currently doing to print them out, one at a time is

```c
for(std::list<std::string>::iterator it=list1.begin(); it!=list1.end(); ++it) {
            cout << *it <<endl;
}
```

Comment: A `for` loop is logically equivalent to having its initialization section followed by `while (condition)`, and with the last part of the `for` statement always being the very last statement executed inside the `while` loop. Simply take what you need to do here, and structure it this way, a logically-equivalent `while` loop.

Comment: Libraries might propose a zip_iterator for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are probably cleverer ways to do it, but this will work (note that if the lists are different lengths, it will only print as many item-pairs as there are items in the shorter list):

```
  for(std::list<std::string>::iterator it1=list1.begin(), it2=list2.begin();
     (it1!=list1.end())&&(it2!=list2.end());
     ++it1, ++it2) 
  {
     std::cout << *it1 << " : " << *it2 << std::endl;
  }
```